# Android Application working on emulator but not on device

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I created an Android Application that connects to a local MySQL database to retrieve some sample data through JDBC.
When i run the application with the emulator,it works fine and loads the data.
When I run the application from my device,it freezes on loading the data,without errors from the logcat.
Here's the code:

```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Statement;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button bottone;
boolean connected = false;
private TextView nome1;
private TextView cognome1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bottone = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bottone.setOnClickListener(this);
    nome1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_name);
    cognome1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_surname);
}
class ConnectAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private String name;
private String surname;
private ProgressDialog myProgress;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    myProgress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Wait", "Loading..");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.1/prova";
        String user = "myuser";
        String password = "mypsw";

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Driver non caricato");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Errore con url e credenziali!");

        }

        if(connection!= null)
        {System.out.println("Connessione riuscita!");
        connected = true;}
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT NOME,COGNOME FROM amici";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if(!rs.next())
            {System.out.println("Vuota");}
            else
            {
                do{
                    name = rs.getString("NOME");
                    surname = rs.getString("COGNOME");
                }while(rs.next());}
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Query error");
        }
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         if(connected)
                return "Connessione riuscita";
            else return "Connessione non riuscita";
}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {   myProgress.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("Connessione riuscita"))
            {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            nome1.setText(name);
            cognome1.setText(surname);}

            else 
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void connectToDB(View view)
{
     ConnectAsync task = new ConnectAsync();
     task.execute();}
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      connectToDB(v);
      }
 }
```

The IP address i used in the JDBC string is the one i got typing "ipconfig" in windows cmd (IPv4).
The app simply shows a progress dialog until the connection is up,and then retrieves the data from the database putting it into two textviews.

As i said,when i try to connect using the Android Emulator it connects and runs fine,but when i run the application on my Device the application freezes at getting connection (progress dialog keeps loading) and no errors are given in the logcat.
I checked the minimum SDK required,and it matches with my phone Android version.

I think it's something related to the way MySQL database handles the connection requests from the emulator and from the device...any help is appreciated,thanks.

P.S: MySQL configuration file (my.ini) has the following parameters:

```
 ....

 [mysqld]
 bind-address= *
 # skip-networking
 ...
 ...
 wait_timeout = 30
 interactive_timeout = 30
 connect_timeout = 30
```

Comment: Let me ask a stupid question, is your phone connected to your wifi?

Comment: yeah,they share the same wifi.
the only doubt I have is about a wifi signal extender that i have plugged in my house,but i don't think it can cause this kind of problems

Comment: you should be able to connect to your local machine from your phone or vice versa as long as they're both on the same network (wifi).  If not sure, turn off mobile service and enable wifi to access the internet, this will answer your extender question.

Comment: IOW, if it works on the emulator and not the device, don't post code problems first.  Instead, verify that the device can contact the local network.  Then, if that tests OK, it's possible that your program has a problem.  Verify that by writing an extremely simple program that connects to a webserver (or service) running on a local machine.

Comment: Rmember, your goal is to solve the problem - so first, verify what the problem is.  (Hint: it's probably not your program that already works on the emulator to the local machine that is failing)

Comment: I checked:my phone can actually access the local Wifi,the same Wifi accessed by my PC.

Comment: And your dead simple application loaded on the phone can access your dead simple application loaded on a local PC?  Or, your dead simple application (http POST to google.com) works also?